# UITableView sections to always stay within view

Tags: ios, uitableview, visible, always-on-top

I have a UITableView with 3 sections:

**section 1:**
the header title of this section is "Players" and the cotent is exactly 1 cell containing a horizontal list of 1-4 players names.

**section 2:**
the header title of this section is "Rounds" and the content is X cells each containing a horizontal list of each respective players score for round X.

**section 3:**
the header title of this section is "Totals" and the content is exactly 1 cell containing the sum of each player's round scores.

Right now, all these sections scroll as section 2 expands with new rounds, but I want to always keep section 1 at the top of the screen, and have section 3 right below section 2, until it expands down to the bottom of the screen and then stop and stay there.

I guess I could do this with 3 separate table views inside a UIView but that seems kind of convoluted and I section 3 wouldn't stay right below section 2 until it expanded to the bottom of the screen; it would just always be at the bottom...

Is there a way to keep a table section/row always visible, and have the others still scrollable?

Answer (score 3):

Use 3 UITableViews as you discussed, and just animate the position of the Third tableview to move it down each time you add a cell to tableView 2, until it reaches the bottom of the screen then just leave it there.  (Also you will need to expand the height of tableView 2 as you add elements to it.)

Otherwise, like Cyrille said, there is no way to implement that with one tableview only.

Answer (score 2):

Not with the standard UITableView implementation, no.

Comment: Has anyone already tried putting a nested UITableView as a first-level-UITableView's `tableHeaderView` ? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11070875/526547