# UITableView in table view's headerView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uikit

Relating to [UITableView sections to always stay within view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11053222/526547) but I got an idea I'm not sure of:

Has anyone ever tried to nest a `UITableView` in another `UITableView`, whether by putting the second one as the `tableHeaderView` or as a section header of the first one?

Comment: uitableview is also a view so it can be possible

Comment: It is possible, but how well does it perform?

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is derived from `UIScrollView`. It is generally not a good idea to have a scroll view inside a scroll view (exception: when the scrolling directions are perpendicular to each other).

Otherwise you would end up with a user interface that is not appropriate for most users.